# Handle cookies in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I can wholly use selenium to log in to a site.

After login to the main user account page (Tab A), I will access a link by performing this code and opening a new tab (Tab B).

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="iaes"]/a'))).click()
```

**Problem: Each tab use different values of cookies/sessions**

Then, if I run

```
driver_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

It will be supposed to get all the cookies from both tabs??

However, when I inspect the cookies dict and network tab in the browser. `drive.get_cookies()` can only get Tab A cookies but not include Tab B.

I resolve this by pasting the actual link to `driver.get()`.

Running `driver.get_cookies()` again is the cookies that I want in order to post requests to the site to get a response (otherwise, the site responded the session is expired)

I note that
module **broswer_cookies3** can naturally handle this in Chrome. How can I do the same behavior in selenium?

Hope my description is clear.